# Is it requirement to have a custom skill in Virtual Assistant Bot? or implement it in Virtual Assistant bot itself?

Tags: botframework

Virtual Assistant v1.0 provides a latest enterprise grade bot template that will replace previously used Enterprise Bot template. I totally understand the reason for VA bot + bot skills, it allows nice extension, but additional deployment steps.
In my case I don't want to have a custom skill, why not implementing my custom skill in the Virtual Assistant bot itself? Inside the maindialog, RouteStepsAsync, currently it is checking for the skill intent, and calls the skill dialog which comes from skills project, same way, check for my custom skill intent and start the dialog ( BeginDialogAsync). what is the Microsoft's recommendation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can totally implement custom logic in your VA. The idea of skills is that they can be modular and used for different/multiple assistants. It is not required to have a skill. You can have the VA alone.